# Update Firebase query from filter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I use VueFire to connect to my database which has a list of recipes, I load all recipes using this code (relavant snippets)

```
firebase: {
    recipes: database.ref('recipes'),
  },

  data () {
    return {
      activeFilter: Filters.selected //returns active filter from child component for example 'pie'
    };
  },
```

In < template>

```
<li v-for="(recipe, idx) in recipes" :key="idx" class="recipe">
  <a>{{ recipe.name }} - {{ recipe.type }}</a>
</li>
```

Now if I change the filter I want to update `sites` to only return the filtered items. In my previous code (not Vue.js) I had this working:

```
var filteredRecipes = ref.child('recipes').orderByChild('type/pie').equalTo(true);
```

But how do I use this code to be able to filter in my Vue.js app?

Comment: I really haven't tried using Firebase with VueFire, but this may help:
`watch: {
        "$firebaseRefs.activeFilter": function() {
            this.recipes = ref.child('recipes').orderByChild('type/pie').equalTo(true)
        }
    }`

Comment: ref.child('receipes') are you sure it's receipes not recipes?

Comment: My bad that was a typo from copying, I will try that snippet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you need to unbind and rebind again:

```
watch: {
  'activeFilter': {
    deep: true,
    handler: function(newVal, oldVal) {
      this.$unbind('recipes')
      this.$bindAsArray('recipes', database.ref.child('recipes').orderByChild('type/' + newVal).equalTo(true))
    }
  }
}
```

I think there is a better solution, you bind all data and do filter on UI. You don't need to unbind and rebind every time filter is changed.

```
computed: {
  filterRecipies() {
    const data = this.recipes || [
    if (this.activeFilter) {
       return data.filter(dataItem => dataItem.type.pie)
    }
    return data
  }
}
```